# How to correctly update SNMP4j agent MIB values correctly

Tags: java, network-programming, snmp, snmp4j

I'm trying to create an SNMP4j agent and am finding it difficult to understand the process correctly. I have successfully created an agent that can be queried from the command line using snmpwalk. What I am having difficulty with is understanding how I am meant to update the values stored in my implemented MIB.

The following shows the relevant code I use for creating the MIB (I implement Host-Resources-MIB)

```
        agent = new Agent("0.0.0.0/" + port);
        agent.start();
        agent.unregisterManagedObject(agent.getSnmpv2MIB());
        modules = new Modules(DefaultMOFactory.getInstance());
        HrSWRunEntryRow thisRow = modules.getHostResourcesMib().getHrSWRunEntry()
                .createRow(oidHrSWRunEntry);

        final OID ashEnterpriseMIB = new OID(".1.3.6.1.4.1.49266.0"); 

        thisRow.setHrSWRunIndex(new Integer32(1));
        thisRow.setHrSWRunName(new OctetString("RunnableAgent"));
        thisRow.setHrSWRunID(ashEnterpriseMIB);
        thisRow.setHrSWRunPath(new OctetString("All is good in the world")); // Max 128 characters
        thisRow.setHrSWRunParameters(new OctetString("Everything is working")); // Max 128 characters
        thisRow.setHrSWRunType(new Integer32(HrSWRunTypeEnum.application));
        thisRow.setHrSWRunStatus(new Integer32(HrSWRunStatusEnum.running));

        modules.getHostResourcesMib().getHrSWRunEntry().addRow(thisRow);

        agent.registerManagedObject(modules.getHostResourcesMib());
```

This appears to be sufficient to create a runnable agent. What I do not understand is how I am meant to change the values stored in the MIB (how do I, for example, change the value of HrSWRunStatus). There seem to be a few kludge ways but they don't seem to fit with the way the library is written.

I have come across numerous references to using/overriding the methods

- prepare
- commit
- undo
- cleanup

But cannot find any examples where this is done. Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

In `protected void registerManagedObjects()`, you need to do something like `new MOMutableColumn(columnId, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_INTEGER, MOAccessImpl.ACCESS_READ_WRITE, null);` for your **HrSWRunStatus**. Take a look at the `TestAgent.java` example of SNMP4J-agent source.